# Using SUM based on ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Basically what I'm trying to do, there are users that have applicable services within a date range (monthly)

I want to be able to show the User's available time for services (in hours), as well as how many hours they have scheduled based a table that holds appointment data

So I want it to basically look like

```
user             service             available         scheduled
-----------------------------------------------------------------
User1            Service1            120               7
User1            Service2            40                0
```

The Scheduled column is calculated by taking the `SUM` of the `Start` and `End` fields in my `Appointment` table.

Now my problem is that if there are no appointments scheduled, I'm unsure of how to still show the information that I'm wanting above.

The relationship between the tables are the following:

- 1 NOA per User
- Multiple Services per NOA
- 1 FormType per Service
- Appointment holds FormTypeID as a `FK`
- ClientAppointment holds the AppointmentID and UserID (the same user with the assigned NOA)

---

```
SELECT

 --NOA
 noa.noaID, noa.userID as 'ClientUserID', 

 --Service
 service.BillingCode + service.MOD1 + service.MOD2 + service.MOD3 + service.MOD4 AS     BillingCode, service.FormTypeID, service.StartDate, service.EndDate, service.CurrentUnits, service.Adjustment,

 --Scheduler
 scheduler.* 
 FROM LEL_NOA noa
 LEFT JOIN LEL_Service service ON service.noaID = noa.noaID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (
 SELECT ca.ClientID, SUM(DATEDIFF(second, a.Start, a.[End]) / 3600) as ScheduledUnits        FROM LEL_Scheduler_Appointment a
 LEFT JOIN LEL_Scheduler_ClientAppointment ca ON a.ApptID = ca.ApptID
 WHERE a.Start BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
   AND a.[End] BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
 GROUP BY ca.ClientID

 ) AS scheduler ON noa.UserID = scheduler.ClientID

WHERE noa.UserID = 4
AND service.StartDate BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
AND service.EndDate BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'

ORDER BY 'ClientUserID', BillingCode, FormTypeID, StartDate
```

The above procedure will pull back for the month, 21 availabl, 7 scheduled, but the person with a `UserID = 4` has another service for that time period and I would like to show the information with 0 hours scheduled as the next item in my table.

---

```
(noaID, ClientUserID, BillingCode, FormTypeID, StartDate, EndDate, CurrentUnits,     Adjustment, ScheduledUnits) VALUES
(203, 25, 'x888', 6, '4/16/2012 4:24:19 PM', '4/16/2012 4:24:19 PM', 0, 0, 5.000000), 
(203, 25, 'x999', 1, '4/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', '4/30/2012 12:00:00 AM', 10, 0, 5.000000)
```

The problem is that the first entry, there aren't any appointments scheduled but yet it's still showing 5 (which the second sum is correct)

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p?

Comment: Added to the bottom, INSERT format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reworking your query to use an inline sub-query. Performance might suffer, but it will be easier to get a correct query.

```
SELECT
--NOA
noa.noaID, noa.userID as ClientUserID, 
--Service
service.BillingCode + service.MOD1 + service.MOD2 + service.MOD3 + service.MOD4 AS BillingCode,
service.FormTypeID, service.StartDate, service.EndDate, service.CurrentUnits, service.Adjustment,
--Scheduler
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, a.Start, a.[End]) / 3600), 0) as ScheduledUnits
    FROM LEL_Scheduler_Appointment a
        INNER JOIN LEL_Scheduler_ClientAppointment ca ON a.ApptID = ca.ApptID
    WHERE a.Start BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
        AND a.[End] BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
        AND ca.ClientID = noa.UserID
        AND a.ServiceID = FormTypeID
) as ScheduledUnits
FROM LEL_NOA noa
    LEFT JOIN LEL_Service service ON service.noaID = noa.noaID
WHERE noa.UserID = 4
    AND service.StartDate BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
    AND service.EndDate BETWEEN '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
ORDER BY ClientUserID, BillingCode, FormTypeID, StartDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Above the ORDER BY clause, add a UNION ALL line and then a new SELECT query that specifically pulls the info for that same user with no schedule.  Just make sure the new query has the same columns as the top query, even if you have to hard-code NULL values.  Here's the general syntax:

```
SELECT [stuff] FROM Table1 WHERE [A]
UNION ALL
SELECT [samestuff] FROM Table1 WHERE [B]
ORDER BY [somestuff]
```

Comment: FYI, UNION ALL gives everything and is faster while just UNION excludes duplicate lines between the two data sets but is slower.